# what type of parser is bison?

Tags: parser-generator

what type of parser is bison. is it a LALR(1) or LR(1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [both](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Generalized-LR-Parsing).

By default, it produces LALR(1) parsers.

With the explicit option `%glr-parser`, it'll produce an LR(1) parser.

Comment: "Both" is simply wrong.  Tradititional bison *is* LALR(1).  However, the newer %glr-parser option does not produce an *LR(1)* parser as I understand it. It produces a *GLR* parser, which happens to use LALR(1) parsing tables. [I've implmented GLR parsers; they don't need anything "LR(1)"].

Answer (score 1):

Yep, since version 2.5, Bison does support several types of LR parsers: LALR(1), canonical LR(1), and IELR(1).  See the documentation about "lr.type", for instance [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/LR-Table-Construction.html#LR-Table-Construction.).